# Showing a PopUp Window from another PopUp Window

Tags: java, android, eclipse, popupwindow, android-context

I have created an application that has a PopupWindow with two AutoComplete EditText views. The AutoCompletes have an OnTextChangeListener, which is suppose to trigger a DropDown Popup Window with suggestions everytime a new character is entered. However, when I run the test this is the Logcat(errors only) I get.

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token    android.view.ViewRoot$W@40aab400 is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:450)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:283)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:532)
at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:943)
at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:855)
at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:588)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1064)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:943)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:926)
at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I need help with a suggestion of how I can go about showing a DropDown Popup Window from a Popup Window.

As Chris suggested the code is as follows.

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

/** Returns the place description corresponding to the selected item */
@Override
protected CharSequence convertSelectionToString(Object selectedItem) {
    /** Each item in the autocompetetextview suggestion list is a hashmap object */
    HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) selectedItem;
    return hm.get("description");
    }
}
```

This is my CustomAutoComplete Class

```
public void popupInit() {

    popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.poplayout, null);
    insidePopupButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    popUp = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popUp.setFocusable(true);
    popUp.setOutsideTouchable(isRestricted());
    test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



}
```

This function initialises the parent Popup Window which has the two CustomAutoComplete.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.Searchview) {

        popUp.showAtLocation(getWindow().getDecorView(),Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
        popUp.isFocusable();
        popUp.setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.poplayout, null, false));
        from = (AutoCompleteTextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.origin_pl);
        to = (AutoCompleteTextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.destination_pl);
        from.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)   {
                placesTask = new PlacesTask();
                placesTask.execute(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        to.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                placesTask = new PlacesTask();
                placesTask.execute(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        }); 
        return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.cancelview) {

        popUp.dismiss();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is section create a menuItem than when clicked, will show the main Popup window and set the OnTextXhangeListeners for Both the AutoCompleteTextViews

```
private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... place) {
        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
        String key = "key=Ajjljlljoojljlljljljllsg9A3doO6dfQ";

        String input="";

        try {
            input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // place type to be searched
        String types = "types=geocode";

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        try{
            // Fetching the data from we service
            data = downloadUrl(url);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // Creating ParserTask
        parserTask = new ParserTaskJ();

        // Starting Parsing the JSON string returned by Web Service
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}
/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTaskJ extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

    JSONObject jObject;

    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;

        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
            places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

        String[] from_in = new String[] { "description"};
        int[] to_in = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

        // Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from_in, to_in);

        // Setting the adapter
        if (from.hasFocus()) {
        from.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        if (to.hasFocus()) {
            to.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my AsyncTask for setting up the AutoComplete and Network Activity.

I hope this all makes sense. The reason I had omitted the code in the beginning was its lengthiness.

Thank you.

Comment: I would post my code if was you. It is possible to nest alertdialogs, but nobody can help you if you do not at least post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those in the future that might come across my question. I decided to go with an AlertDialog with two AutoComplete Text views. Its much easier to use and is less restricted by Contexts and ViewGroups etc.